# ext js controller does not listen events (looks easy but doesn't work)

Tags: javascript, extjs, controller

My controller does not listen to button click event. I tried different selectors  and so on, but nothing work. Here code of my start js file, controller and view. There are no syntax errors.

```
Ext.require([
        'Ext.grid.*',
        'Ext.data.*',
        'Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature',
        'ExtApp.controller.refBook.RefGrid',
        'ExtApp.view.refBook.RefGrid'
        ]);

Ext.onReady(function () {
    Ext.create("ExtApp.view.refBook.RefGrid");
});


Ext.define('ExtApp.view.refBook.RefGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.Button',
    alias: 'widget.testViewButton',
    text: 'Click me',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});


Ext.define('ExtApp.controller.refBook.RefGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    views: [
        'refBook.RefGrid'
    ],

    init: function () {
        this.control({

            "testViewButton": {
                click:function(){alert('aaa');}
            },

            ////I tried this but no response too
            //"button": {
            //    click: function () { alert('fff'); }
            //}
        });
    }
});
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: seems like "init" function is not called

Comment: Is this the whole code? Where's the application?

Comment: yes, whole code... i dont use application, i use just like this

Comment: AFAIK MVC doesn't work without application. Look at the MVC tutorial. Add some `console.log` in your code. It seems like your controller is defined but never initialized. This is applications duty.